# How to fix a loud, vibrating Maytag top loading washer?

Tags: repair

I have an older Maytag top loading washer that sits on a concrete floor. It has never vibrated in all these years, except when it contained an unbalanced load---easy fix. Now it vibrates and moves around making a very loud sound that scares the pets, no matter what size load and no matter how well balanced the load is, starting with the spin cycle. What are the most probable causes for this and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

Ensuring the washer is level is always a good thing to do for anyone owning a washer. This sounds more major than a simple leveling. I think one of the suspension springs are either broken or has become detached. By removing the sheet metal cabinet, it shouldn't be too hard to check the springs. Depending on where the problem lies, it could be an easy fix or major surgery.

I believe this machine has 3 large lateral springs and a smaller vertical spring in back. This vertical spring can lose it's lower attachment to the frame because the frame rusts out. The solution here is to drill a new attachment hole nearby in competent metal and reattach the spring in the new hole.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the washer is level. This can usually be accomplished using the adjustable feet of the machine, though may require shims in extreme cases.

1. Place a level on top of the washer, running from back to front.
2. Adjust the feet accordingly to get the bubble in the middle.
3. Place the level on top of the washer, running from left to right.
4. Adjust the feet accordingly to get the bubble in the middle.
5. Repeat steps 1-4 until the washer is level in both directions.